# 3D surface plot difficult to put axis ticks and lables

Tags: plotting

I have a surface plot, I wanted to fix the axis labels and ticks to this plot, but I am unable to fix this. How to do this, Here is the code I tried. the x-axis limits 1e-3 to 1e12, and Y-axis is also the same as the x-axis.

```
p[1] = ListPlot3D[data1, 
   AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(K\), \(1\)]\)", 
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(K\), \(2\)]\)", "λ"}, 
   PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None, PlotTheme -> "LightMesh", 
   PlotStyle -> {Gray}, BoundaryStyle -> Thick, 
   Ticks -> {FindDivisions[{Log[10, .001], Log[10, 1*^12]}, 8], 
     FindDivisions[{Log[10, .001], Log[10, 1*^12]}, 8], Automatic}, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 3, ColorFunction -> "SouthwestColors"];
```

[image: 3Dsurface plot]

Comment: If you need to plot in logarithmic scale, you can use `ScalingFunctions` option: `ListPlot3D[..., ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log", Identity}]`, and no need for manual specification of ticks (remove your `Ticks -> ...` option).

Comment: @Alx  your suggestion is not working. `ListPlot3D[data1, 
  AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(K\), \(1\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(K\), \(2\)]\)", "\[Lambda]"}, Mesh -> None, 
  PlotTheme -> "LightMesh", PlotStyle -> {Gray}, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log", Identity}, PlotRange -> All, 
  BoundaryStyle -> Thick, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
  ColorFunction -> "SouthwestColors"];`

Comment: I don't have your `data1`, so I tested with `ListPlot3D[RandomReal[{1, 10000}, {1000, 3}], ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log", Identity}]`, and I see logarithmic tics on `X` and `Y` axes.